# Does org-mode has a assembly highlight?

Tags: org-mode

here is my question, does org-mode has a assembly highlight?

I prefer AT&T syntax, but Intel syntax is also fine.

For exmaple:

I know org-mode has a code highlighting like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(+ 1 2 3 4)
#+END_SRC
```

So what I am asking is that how can I highlighting assembly code ?

Like this?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC Assembly
mov 1, %eax
#+END_SRC
```

But it cannot work...

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please?  Do you mean syntax highlighting (ie, font-locking)?  And, if so, how does your question relate to `org-mode`?

Comment: Let me update it @Dan

Comment: Usually, if you have a `foo-mode` in Emacs, then `#+begin_src foo` will pick up the highlighting and editing via `C-'` without any extra work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
#+begin_src asm
```

The assembly mode in Emacs is called `asm-mode`.  You can find that name by opening an assembly file and typing `M-: major-mode` (assuming that Emacs automatically switches to the correct mode for your files).  For `#+begin_src`, org-mode appends `-mode` to the language name given, which is why `#+begin_src asm` leads to `asm-mode` being used.

Comment: doesn't work for me